# How to find difference of two fields from two consecutive rows in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql log table of machine in the following format.

```
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Event_Id | Event_Type | Machine_No | Operator  | Time Stamp          | Shift | Reason     | Count |
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 101      | Up         | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-06-09 01:03:55 | S1    | Start      | 1     |
    | 102      | Up         | Machine2   | operator2 | 2012-06-09 01:03:55 | S1    | Start      | 1     |
    | 103      | Up         | Machine3   | operator3 | 2012-06-09 01:03:55 | S1    | Start      | 1     |
    | 104      | Down       | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-06-09 02:03:55 | S1    | Break Down | 1     |
    | 101      | Up         | Machine1   | operator1 | 2012-06-09 02:33:55 | S1    | After BD   | 1     |
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the table goes on like this.

by passing the following query.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rpt_machine_log WHERE machine='machine1' AND shift='Shift1'")
```

i was able to get the following output.

```
 101    Up      machine1    operator1   2012-06-09 01:03:55 Shift1  Start of The Shift  1
 106    Down    machine1    operator1   2012-06-09 03:15:55 Shift1  Break               1
 109    Up      machine1    operator1   2012-06-09 03:30:55 Shift1  After The Break     1
 112    Down    machine1    operator1   2012-06-09 03:45:55 Shift1  Break Down          1
 115    Up      machine1    operator1   2012-06-09 05:00:55 Shift1  After Break Down    1
 116    Down    machine1    operator1   2012-06-09 05:30:55 Shift1  Break Down          2
 117    Up      machine1    operator1   2012-06-09 05:45:55 Shift1  After Break Down    2
 118    Down    machine1    operator1   2012-06-09 06:00:55 Shift1  End of Shift        1
```

Now i want to find the difference of each consecutive Up and Down Time in php code.

I also want to add shift2 to same query to display machine1 log for both shift 1 & 2.

since i'm new to php i was not able to solve this.

Can any help me out.

Comment: A few suggestions.  1) You'll probably want to add an order by to your query to guarantee order, 2) You should research [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops to iterate over $data, 3) You should not use mysql_query, but instead use mysqli_query as the use of the former is discouraged

Comment: Who created your log table? What is the PK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get shift2 aswell I'd do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rpt_machine_log 
WHERE machine='machine1' AND (shift='Shift1' OR shift='Shift2')
ORDER BY shift,`Time Stamp`
```

With columns that have spaces or special characters you want to add ` around them. To be honest it is safer to just do this for all columns. Some columns, such as Add would cause a query to fail since add is a reserved keyword in sql.

If you can guarantee that up will always follow down then you could loop through your result:
`while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){}`

After this there are plenty of ways to go to store the data, could try:

```
if(isset($timestamp)){
$difftime=strtotime($row['Time Stamp'])-strtotime($timestamp);
$hours=floor($difftime/3600);
$difftime-=$hours*3600;
$minutes=floor($difftime/60);
$difftime-=$minutes*60;
$seconds=$difftime;
$diff_array[]=$hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;
unset($timestamp);}
else{
$timestamp=$row['Time Stamp'];}
```

And there you have an array of all the time differences.

Obviously if you can't guarantee that up will always come after down, or you want to split up the time diffs for shift1 and shift2 then you will have to add in extra checks to the while loop.

---EDIT---

```
if(isset($timestamp)){
$difftime=strtotime($row['Time Stamp'])-strtotime($timestamp);
$diff_array[]=$difftime;
unset($timestamp);}
else{
$timestamp=$row['Time Stamp'];}

foreach ($diff_array as &$value){
$Uptime += $value;}

$hours=floor($Uptime/3600);
$Uptime-=$hours*3600;
$minutes=floor($Uptime/60);
$Uptime-=$minutes*60;
$seconds=$convert;
$Uptime=$hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;
```

---EDIT2---

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
$array['event_type'][]=$row['event_type'];
$array['timestamp'][]=$row['Time Stamp'];}
```

Now you have an array of two arrays: event_types and timestamps. You could just do this as two distinct arrays too if you want e.g. `$event_type[]=$row['event_type'];` and change the rest accordingly.

You could now do a for loop to iterate over these results and do the checks you need.

```
$count=count($array['event_type']);
for($x=0;$x<$count;$x++){
if($row['event_type'][$x]=='Down' && $row['event_type'][$x+1]=='Up'){
}}
```

Remember to calculate the count before the for loop, putting it in as one of the conditions means it would be calculated every time and therefore has a performance cost.

Also if you want to skip the first result of your mysql results just call `$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($data)` once before the while loop.

Comment: Thank a lot mrmryb. it works great. but i have one doubt. if the table value starts with down followed by up, will it works? i also want to split up the time difference for shift1 and shift2.

Comment: That's why I said you have to guarantee the order for this method, however with `ORDER BY TIME STAMP` on the end of the query you will always get earlier times coming before later times, which from your log seems to suggest an up, down order.
If you did want to order by down first, then switching `$difftime=strtotime($row['Time Stamp'])-strtotime($timestamp);` to `$difftime=strtotime($timestamp)-strtotime($row['Time Stamp']);` should do the trick. It all depends on the order, and if you want to keep it flexible then you'll need to start adding checks.

Comment: The simplest method for seperating shift1 and shift2 without any ifs would be to create arrays based on which shift it is by turning the value into the variable name with `${$row['Shift']}[]=$hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;` and then you have two arrays, $shift1 and $shift2

Comment: one small doubt. when i try to add all the values of array by using, 
`foreach ($diff_array as &$value) {$Uptime += $value;}.` the output was `2`, instead of 3:12:0. How to add all the values of the array to get up time?

Comment: If you want to add them all together you are better off doing the hour:minute:second conversion after you add them all together, they are in the wrong format to be added together currently. I will add an edit on to my answer to reflect this.

Comment: i was trying to start the process from second row, if the row['event_type']=='Down'. i also want to make sure that the next row event type is 'up'. i modified the code like the following. `while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){if($row['event_type'] == 'Down' && ($row['event_type']+1) == 'Up'){//printing Table}`. But i don't get any table in my screen. is there any way to check the two consecutive rows in if loop.

Comment: `$row['event_type']+1` is not valid syntax but I understand what you are attempting to do, unfortunately you cannot skip ahead to the next row like that. If you were to use PDO instead of mysql you could use the [Fetchall](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) function which basically creates arrays within an array, so you could call $row[0]['event_type'] and $row[1]['event_type'] to get the first and second results.
In your case you would need to transfer all the data in to an array first within the while loop, and then manipulate that data as you are trying.
I will add an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this entirely in MySQL by joining back to the table.  Something like this (untested) code should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM rpt_machine_log rpt1, rpt_machine_log rpt2
WHERE rpt1.event_type = "Up"
AND rpt1.machine_no = rpt2.machine_no
AND rpt2.`time stamp` > rpt1.`time stamp`
AND rpt2.event_type = "Down"
```

There are some corner cases, but this should get you started.